# How to avoid jenkins overwritten /var/jenkins_home when starting up for the first time

Tags: docker, jenkins

I want to set up CI/CD platform using Jenkins on Docker, I have a Dockerfile which set up Jenkins with plugins, jobs, pipelines, users and so on. 
But when starting Jenkins I've got a fresh install and all my setup is overwritten. Do I miss changing a flag somewhere?

Comment: Show your code, which sets up `Dockerfile`s and runs `ci`

Comment: Given the shortage of information in this question I can only quess that you are starting a new container every time, which obviously doesn't have the data from the other container that run before. You can start by following the best practice and putting JENKINS_HOME (`/var/jenkins_home`) on a Docker volume. How you do this, depends on the orchestration that you use (Docker Compose etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
  FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root
# force Jenkins to be a sudoer
RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y vim sudo curl\
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

# install docker-ce
RUN apt -y  update && \
    apt -y  upgrade && \
    apt -y install sudo apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common gnupg2 && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add - && \
    add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable" && \
    apt -y update && \
    apt -y install docker-ce

# install Maven 
RUN cd /usr/local && \
    wget https://www-us.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.6.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.tar.gz  && \
    mv apache-maven-3.6.0 apache-maven && \
    rm apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.tar.gz 

COPY maven.sh /etc/profile.d
RUN chmod +x /etc/profile.d/maven.sh

# install Oracle Java 11 
WORKDIR /usr/local
RUN wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; \
    oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" \
    https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11.0.1+13/90cf5d8f270a4347a95050320eef3fb7/jdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf jdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz && \
    rm jdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz


COPY install-plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh
COPY jenkins-support /usr/local/bin/jenkins-support

# install all plugins
COPY plugins.txt /var/jenkins_home/plugins.txt
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh
RUN xargs /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh  < /var/jenkins_home/plugins.txt

# Install all jobs, pipelines, users and environment
ADD jenkins.tar.gz $JENKINS_HOME

# copy script-security disable
COPY groovy/disable-script-security.groovy /var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d

RUN echo 2.0 > /usr/share/jenkins/ref/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
```

Comment: is this your Dockerfile or is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use volumes when you run the container:

For example, the following example , instantiate a container called **jenkins** and mount a path **/my_server/jenkins_home** in the host with **/var/jenkins_home** inside container:

```
docker run -t --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -v /my_server/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

So, when you start or stop the container, this folder in the host server will be intact **/my_server/jenkins_home** and will be used for your container. All configurations in your Jenkins will be ready to use.

## Reference:

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution :

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root
# force Jenkins to be a sudoer
RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get install -y vim sudo curl\
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

ARG JENKINS_HOME=/var/jenkins_home
ENV JENKINS_HOME $JENKINS_HOME
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false

# install docker-ce
RUN apt -y  update && \
    apt -y  upgrade && \
    apt -y install sudo apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common gnupg2 && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add - && \
    add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable" && \
    apt -y update && \
    apt -y install docker-ce

# install Maven
RUN cd /usr/local && \
    wget https://www-us.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.6.0/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.tar.gz  && \
    mv apache-maven-3.6.0 apache-maven && \
    rm apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.tar.gz

COPY maven.sh /etc/profile.d
RUN chmod +x /etc/profile.d/maven.sh

# install Oracle Java 11
WORKDIR /usr/local
RUN wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; \
    oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" \
    https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/11.0.1+13/90cf5d8f270a4347a95050320eef3fb7/jdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf jdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz && \
    rm jdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz


COPY install-plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh
COPY jenkins-support /usr/local/bin/jenkins-support

# install all plugins
COPY plugins.txt /var/jenkins_home/plugins.txt
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh
RUN xargs /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh  < /var/jenkins_home/plugins.txt

# Install all jobs, pipelines, users and environment
ADD jenkins.tar.gz /usr/share/jenkins/ref/

# copy script-security disable
COPY groovy/disable-script-security.groovy /var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d
```

Comment: JAVA_OPTS was missing, so the runSetupWizard to equal to False and I have to copy all my tar.gz file to /usr/share/jenkins/ref/. That prevents my files being overwritten by Jenkins.

Comment: So now I could share my jobs and pipelines within a Dockerfile for training purpose withmy students. All plugins are already setup and Jenkins environment, SonarQube, Nexus, Jmeter et Selenium are defined in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that worked for me was to append -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard to jenkins options. See my dockerfile below:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false -Djenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state=2.0

ADD helix-core-server.tgz /home/perforce/

COPY persistent_config/ /var/jenkins_home/

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y vim

RUN mv /home/perforce/p4 /usr/bin

USER jenkins
```